# drush failure on error in drupal 7

Tags: 7, drush, migrations

My initial installation of Drush couldn't even recognize commands such as "drush migrate-status", therefore I reinstalled drush and followed the steps in the included README.

After reinstallation, drush now recognizes the command "drush migrate-status", hwoever it is throwing an error and crashing. I am confused as I have not even enabled the migrate_example module included with the Migrate module, however drush is throwing the error message below:

```
require_once(/var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/migrate_example/beer.inc):[warning]
failed to open stream: No such file or directory bootstrap.inc:3024
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/migrate_example/beer.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/drupal7/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3024
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: require_once(): Failed opening required
'/var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/migrate_example/beer.inc'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
/var/www/drupal7/includes/bootstrap.inc, line 3024
```

This all seems very cryptic to me, especially when I have not enabled the migrate_example module and I have the migrate_example directory under migrate.

Could someone please explain why drush might be throwing this error?

Comment: It sounds like the file `/var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/migrate_example/beer.inc` is missing.  Have you checked it actually exists?

Comment: @chapabu thank you for pointing that out, my migrate_example was under migrate/, i just had to move it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the file `/var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/migrate_example/beer.inc` is missing.

Comment: hmm well i recognize another issue (i don't know why drupal hates me), now that i brought the migrate_example folder to var/www/sites/all/modules, i can no longer see it under the migrate UI, but drush now recognizes it...would you know what could be wrong? i have been informed that migrate UI only displays what drush sees...

Comment: Is it actually at `var/www/sites/all/modules`?  Shouldn't it be at `var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules` if I'm reading the rest of your folder structure correctly?

Comment: chapabu, sorry you are right i made a mistake while typing that out. it is in var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules, i put all the modules in there but the migrate UI is not reading it

Comment: I am facing the same error, but it seems that mine is a custom .inc file in my migrate module example, only problem is that its on the right path...this didnt solve it for me, trying to troubleshoot more